# Implementing a Priority Queue as a Stack Java

Tags: java, stack, queue, implementation, priority-queue

I've implemented my program but I am getting an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException`

This is the code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class BasePQStack<Item> implements Stack<Item> {

// TODO: implement this object.
private int N = 0;
private MaxPQ<Compare> pq = new MaxPQ<>();
private int count;

public BasePQStack() {
    count = 0;

}

/**
 * entry point for sample output..
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> S = new BasePQStack<Integer>();

    S.push(new Integer(2));
    S.push(new Integer(7));
    Integer W = S.pop();
    S.push(new Integer(8));
    S.push(new Integer(5));
    ;
    Integer X = S.pop();
    Integer Y = S.peek();
    S.push(new Integer(3));
    Integer Z = S.pop();

    System.out.println("Testing: ");
    System.out.println(W);
    System.out.println(X);
    System.out.println(Y);
    System.out.println(Z);
}

@Override
public Item push(Item item) {
    Compare x = new Compare(item, count);
    pq.insert(x);
    count++;
    N++;

    return item;
}

@Override
public Item pop() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");

    else {
        Item var = (Item) pq.delMax();
        N--;
        return var;
    }
}

@Override
public Item peek() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");

    else {
        Item var = (Item) pq.delMax();
        push(var);
        return var;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return N;
}

public class Compare implements Comparable<Compare> {
    private Item value;
    private int a;

    public Compare(Item value, int a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Compare x) {
        if (this.a > x.a)
            return 1;
        if (this.a < x.a)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public Item getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "item {" + "value = " + value + ",a = " + a + '}';
    }
}
```

}

The message I am getting from the console is BasePQStack$Compare cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer. I've tried to do many castings but could not figure anything out as it just led to more error

The output of the code should be:

7

5

8

3

Comment: You should probably replace this two lines `Item var = (Item) pq.delMax();` with `Item var = (Item) pq.delMax().getValue();`

Comment: @JoseDaSilva you're the best! That was all I needed, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I posted an answer in case you want to accept it.

Comment: Are you sure the output order should be 7,5,8,3? It looks to me that it should be 7,5,3,8. After all, 3 is the last item pushed, so the `pop` right after it should pop 3, not 8. Also, your title is unclear. I would suggest: "Using a priority queue to implement a stack"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably replace this line

```
Item var = (Item) pq.delMax()
```

With

```
Item var = (Item) pq.delMax().getValue();
```

Because `delMax()` returns a compare object and you need a Item object.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html): Class cast exceptions are "thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance".

From the code you posted, it looks like it could be occurring when you attempt to cast something to an Item:

```
Item var = (Item) pq.delMax();
```

Probably because your queue does not contain objects of type Item, it contains objects of type Compare. In general be careful when you decide to downcast because the compiler errors are there to help you.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense I used Jose's idea for calling the getValue() method from my Comparable class and that did that trick

Answer (score 0):

Your MaxPQ Key is of type Compare and when you push an Integer it gets wrapped in a Compare before being inserted into the MaxPQ.

The problem is when you pop or peek you do not do any unwrapping of the Compare to get back to the Integer. This is why you get a ClassCastException on any line that calls `pop()` or `peek()`. You are treating the Compare as if it is an Integer.

You need to modify your `pop()` and `peek()` methods as follows;

```
    @Override
    public Item pop() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");
            } else {
                    Item var = (Item) pq.delMax().getValue();
                    N--;
                    return var;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public Item peek() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("no such element");
            } else {
                    Item var = (Item) pq.delMax().getValue();
                    push(var);
                    return var;
            }
    }
```

Note the use of `getValue()`. This is what does the unwrapping I mentioned above i.e. it gets the Integer out of the Compare for you.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! the unwrapping was all I needed